# grails encoding in html attributes

Tags: grails, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

Everything is working fine with the greek characters except for the greek characters that included in html attributes.

Grails: 1.3.7
Config.groovy:

```
 grails.views.default.codec = "none" // none, html, base64
 grails.views.gsp.encoding = "UTF-8"
 grails.converters.encoding = "UTF-8"
```

My test html page is the following:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" %>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test title</title>
    <meta name="keywords" content="ελληνικό τεστ"/>
  </head>
  <body>
     Greek Test Encoding
  </body>
 </html>
```

The response of the server is:

```
<html>
  <head>
   <title>Test title</title>
    <meta name="keywords" content="&epsilon;&lambda;&lambda;&eta;&nu;&iota;&kappa;ό &tau;&epsilon;&sigma;&tau;"/>
  </head>
  <body>
   Greek Test Encoding
  </body>
</html>
```

Why it cannot display the greek characters inside the content attribute ??

Answer (score 1):

Try to set Config.groovy's grails.views.default.codec='html' to get HTML escaping by default  in the application.

If you want to set for default codec for page only:

```
<%@page defaultCodec="html" %>
```

There is some information in [GRAILS-2945](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-2945) and [GRAILS-1827](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-1827)